# list the taxonomy terms linked to the corresponding taxonomy nodes

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-taxonomy

in drupal, after installing the taxonomy node module, I can create a node explaining the taxonomy term. That's working fine.

Now, I would like to list the taxonomy terms of a giving node where each term of the list is a link to the node of that term.

In another words:

```
$listOfTaxonomyTerms = taxonomyTermsByNode($nodeID);

$linkToTaxonomyNode = TaxonomyNodeLinkByTerm($listOfTaxonomyTerms[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to answer my own question. It wouldn't fit the comment text area.

I guess I just needed to make the question to start thinking about the answer. 
So, I made a function on template.php. This collects the urls to the taxonomy nodes and makes some links with the taxonomy terms:

```
function listaNodeSectores($geturl){
    //get alias of URL
    $path = drupal_get_path_alias($geturl['q']);
    //break path into an array
    $pathArray = explode('/', $path);
    $arraysize = sizeof($pathArray);

    if ($arraysize>0) {
      $nodeId = $pathArray[$arraysize - 1];
    }
//  echo "nodeID: ".$nodeId;

    $node = node_load($nodeId);
    $termos = taxonomy_node_get_terms($node);

    foreach($termos as $term){
        $termNodeID = _taxonomynode_get_nid_from_tid($term->tid) ;
        $termNode = node_load($termNodeID);

        $tmp = $pathArray;
        $tmp[$arraysize - 1] = $termNodeID;
        $tmp2 = implode('/', $tmp);
        // devolve os urls completos:
        $termNodeUrls[] = '<a href="'.url($tmp2).'">'.$termNode->title.'</a>';

    }

    return  $termNodeUrls;
}
```